# Encoding and rewriting of URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-rewriting, urlencode

We use URL rewriting or cookies to maintain session across a web server and a browser because they communicate using HTTP protocol which is stateless in nature. Because of its stateless nature, server never recognizes any client(browser) whether it has made any request previously or not. We therefore need to maintain a unique identifier in between them.

When a browser (client) doesn't support cookies or cookies are disabled on the browser, the technique called *URL rewriting* is used and the `sessionID` needs to be encoded in the URL such as,

```
try
{
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("index.jsp?param=value"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Regrading a normal link in JSP, I use the JSTL's [`<c:url>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tag like,

```
<c:url value="Category.htm" var="url">
    <c:param name="id" value="${row.category.catId}"/>
</c:url>

<a href="${url}" 
   name="catId${row.category.catId}" 
   title="Click to view the details.">${row.category.catName}
</a>
```

It is embedded within a `<c:forEach>` loop.

But  if the browser supports cookies or session tracking is turned off, URL encoding is unnecessary and it doesn't take place.

So, in that case, what if a URI or a query contains special characters like `+`, `&`, `@`?

They need to be encoded and if a URI and a query string were encoded separately, would `URL rewriting` automatically done, in case cookies are disabled or not supported by a browser like?

```
URI uri = new URI(
                  "http", 
                  null, 
                  request.getServerName(), 
                  request.getServerPort(), "/WebApp/index.jsp", 
                  "param="+URLEncoder.encode("some value@+", "UTF-8"), null);

String uriString = uri.toASCIIString();
```

and in this case the parameter `param` needs to be decoded while retrieving,

```
out.println(URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("param"), "UTF-8")");
```

What about the URL rewriting in this case, I'm unsure whether it is done by the Servlet Container or to be handled separately on our own.

---

One additional thing, while using `RequestDispatcher`, `<jsp:forward page="index.jsp"/>` and `<jsp:include page="template.jsp"/>`, is it necessary to take care of URL encode like?

```
try
{
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=
    request.getRequestDispatcher(response.encodeURL("index.jsp?param=value"));

    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

and I always use `<c:url>` with the form's action attribute like (regarding Spring),

```
<c:url value="${param.url}" var="url">
    <c:param name="id" value="${param.id}"/>
</c:url>

<form:form action="${url}" id="dataForm" name="dataForm" method="post" commandName="someBean">
    .

    .

    .
</form:form>
```

It refers to the current URL. Is it really required (even though I'm not supplying any parameter(s))?

Comment: Its difficult to understant what is the question? Can you plz state ur problem first and then provide details in ur post

Answer (score 0):

About the last question, experience with Spring 3.0.5 tells that you can omit the action attribute in form:form , it will user the current URL and append the session ID parameter in case cookies are not used.

Related to this, is it possible to use a shorter syntax, something like <form:form action="<c:url value="foo"/>" ... ?
This exact syntax does not work, as tags can not be nested this way. The usage of an extra variable is a bit too long to my taste.